# Korn shell timeout/kill script

Tags: shell, process, ksh, kill

I am trying to write a simple Korn shell script to execute a loading process. The process occasionally runs into connectivity issues, so I need to kill it if it runs too long.

I have been trying the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh 
. /home/dw/script/load.ksh &
LOADPID=$!
sleep 100
kill $LOADPID
```

Unfortunately, the `kill` command does not kill the process - am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Try `kill -s HUP "$LOADPID"`. And if it still doesn't work, you could try `kill -s KILL "$LOADPID"`.

Also note that it doesn't make sense to run the `.` command in background (that is in another process) as the whole point of the `.` command is to interpret the code in the given file in the current shell process.

Comment: Running `. /some/script &` does have a few uses: the script is executed by the same interpreter, and inherits shell parameters, functions, etc. However none of this is happening in this specific example.